# PHP - send foreach values to mysql database field

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm building my first online store.
So far in every website i made i was able to populate the database by sending $_POST with just one value (a name, an email, whatever...) to an insert query.

But this is the first time i need to store in only one database field many product names.

I have a session that stores product information like name, price, code and quantity.

How can i send the session multiple values, there can be n products stored in session, to a database field?

I tried with foreach loop inside inputs but couldn't do it.

Here is my session foreach loop:

```
<?php
          $total = 0;
          foreach($_SESSION["products"] as $product){       
            $product_name = $product["product_name"]; 
            $product_price = $product["product_price"];
            $product_code = $product["product_code"];
            $product_qty = $product["product_qty"];       
            $subtotal = ($product_price * $product_qty);
            $total = ($total + $subtotal);
        ?>
```

Comment: you want to insert the products in the session in a db table?

Comment: So U've already stored multiple values in session or you need to? IF yes stored then you want to know how to populate multiple data in DB?

Comment: Yes. Thats what i intend to do.

Comment: Can you please be precise..? You want to populate into DB right?

Comment: To store information in the database you can use http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php or http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php. I'd go with PDO.

Comment: *"... i need to store in only one database field many product names."* ... I'm pretty certain you don't - nor should you.

Comment: I don't know what to make of this question.. it's hard to know exactly what your problem is. If you have the information saved in the `$_SESSION`, you'd follow the same protocol as if it was from a `$_POST`.

Comment: If a client can purchase more than 1 product, to store all the names of the products purchased in the row of the client is my problem.

Comment: Store it as JSON in a `text` field, use json_encode before inserting, and json_decode at returning to array back in php. If you wish to keep the array in database (i mean all products in one row).

Comment: Yes JSON. I will try that aproach too. Makes all sense :)

Comment: @AndréCastro - not really, you'd have an `order_header` table which contains things like billing name, address and so on and a separate `order_line` table which holds 1 product (technically cart line) per row. Store the `order_header.id` in the `order_line` table to create a [one-to-many relationship](https://www.bbc.co.uk/education/guides/zvq634j/revision). Storing serialized data in a database (even JSON) is normally a terrible idea.

Comment: Thats another aproach. 1 to * relationship with a foreign key to the table that contains the products. Separate in 2 tables and link them. If the other aproaches faills i will try this one (to do it i have to mess up with the current database)...

Answer (score 1):

As you said You need to store multiple product name for a single row this is how you can do it.

```
<?php
          $total = 0;
          foreach($_SESSION["products"] as $product){       
            $product_name = $product["product_name"]; 
            $products = implode(',', $product_name);
          }
            $sql = "INSERT INTO tablename (productname)
            VALUES ($products)";

    ?>
```

Comment: The problem that is confusing my mind i s that every client can aquire more than 1 product, therefore how to store in just that client purchase row ALL the products the client purchased?

Comment: @Bits Please make an array and put your insert query outside foreach

Comment: So you want to store multiple product in Session right?

Comment: check the question first what exactly needed

Comment: Ok. i will try the array aproach. I will do an array and then paas it to database with foreach loop.

Comment: @BitsPlease I implemented your code, and have to cast $products as array inside foreach loop, but only last array index is saved in database field, others are ignored. And var_dump($products) only throws array last index content.

Comment: @BitsPlease, updated your answer and added cast for array type inside foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after many try i managed to write code to sort the thing out :)

```
foreach($_SESSION["products"] as $product){       
  $product_name = $product["product_name"]; 
  $products[] = implode(',', (array)$product_name);
}

$p = json_encode($products);
var_dump($p);
$sql = "INSERT INTO fatura_mb(carrinho) VALUES ('$p')";
$results = $con->query($sql);
```

The JSON conversion is better than a serialize(), and the implode method was always throwing errors or only echoing the last index from the array.

This way data is well stored in database in a single field as i needed to.

**Thanks to all that helped me :)**